# Exoplayer RTSP url with format "rtsp://ip:port" unable to show preview

Tags: android, mobile, rtsp, exoplayer

Tried below Exoplayer code

// Media Source

```
    MediaSource mediaSource =
            new RtspMediaSource.Factory()
                    .createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri("rtsp://ip:1935/"));
```

//set Media source

```
    player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
```

//prepare  exo-player

```
    player.prepare();
```

//start player

```
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

First use VLC to check your url. You also need to set the surface on which the rendering will happen. For example a textureView:

player.setVideoTextureView(textureDisplay);